# Python: Trying to send attachments via email ~ string error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mime, smtplib

I'm trying to send attachments via email with python but I'm getting this error:

***msg.attach(msgImage)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'attach'***

Here is the code:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage


def send_email():
    fromaddr = 'testevpsa1@gmail.com'
    toaddrs  = 'Toemail'
    global msg
    subject = 'RESPOSTA'
    message = 'Subject: %s\n\n%s' % (subject, msg)

    username = 'testevpsa1@gmail.com'
    password = 'xxxxxxxx'

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username,password)

    fp = open ('C:\Python27\Scripts\pares.txt', 'rb')
    msgImage = MIMEImage (fp.read(), _subtype='txt')
    fp.close()
    msg.attach(msgImage)

    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, message,  msg.as_string())
    server.quit()

msg = 'Email test, please, see the attachments'
send_email()
```

Anyone has a hint of what is the problem?

Comment: Hint: What's the type of `msg`?

Comment: `msg` is a string, but I still don't understand the problem, when the script reads the txt file, is it no able to "attach" the content as a string?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is weird and incorrect. You start using advanced concepts without a basic knowledge of the language, smtp protocol and email module.

`msg` variable in your code has `str` type. `str` is a plain string - a list of characters. It doesn't have method `.attach`.

I guess you wanted to use an instance of the class `email.message` instead of a string. Also, there's no need to use global variable. Global variables are bad, and it's totally unnecessary to use global variable in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, i'm using a global variable because maybe in the future it will be used in another function.

Comment: If you want to write a function that is later to be used by another function, then global variable is the *worst* possible way of passing parameters. You need to use normal function parameter, not a global variable. For example:
`def send_mail(msg):`